# Ways in which one can use grateful

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> I am grateful for the 10 minute short meditations I did today morning

Is this a correct sentence or correct use of the word **grateful**

I found in the dictionary that grateful can be used in two ways:

1. Being thankful for something
2. showing appreciation for something

So in the above I am kind of appreciating the act of doing meditation today morning

Is that correct?

Comment: This looks to me like the practice of "mindful gratitude", especially since the context is meditation. So in this case, it's definition 1, and the speaker is thankful (not to anybody, just thankful) for the benefit they've received from their meditations.

Answer (score 1):

You usually express gratitude or show appreciation to other people. You haven't mentioned other people or entities, so "grateful" isn't the best word there.

More idiomatic would be:

> I am happy about the short 10-minute meditations I did this morning.

Note the other changes.

I think the order of adjectives describing the length of time is better as "short 10-minute", although you could just say "10-minute".